# React.js - Cannot read properties of undefined (selectors) + New Error "enhance your system component first"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently learning react ( and redux as well as redux-sagas) and I am basically making a loading screen while the client is connecting to the backend. However I am having the following error:"

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3WFR.png)

As well as my App.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import './App.css';
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Typography, AppBar } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ClimbingBoxLoader from "react-spinners/ClimbingBoxLoader";
import { Service } from './global/service'
import Orchestrator from './components/Orchestrator'



import CreationSelection from './components/CreationSelection/CreationSelection'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: '30px 100px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '600px',
    border: '2px solid black',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '90%'
    }
  },
  image: {
    marginLeft: '15px'
  },
  wrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',   
    width: '100%'
  },

  loading:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh', 
    marginTop: '0px',
  },

  welcome:{
    color:'cyan',
    textAlign:'justify',
    fontStyle:'italic',
  }

}));


const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(Orchestrator.actionCreators.Connect());
  },[dispatch])

  const isConnected = useSelector(Service.selectors.selectIsConnected)
  
  
  /*const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    },8000)
  },[])*/


  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      
      {(() => {

        if( isConnected == CONNECTION_STATES.CONNECTING){
          return(
            <div className={classes.loading} > 
            <ClimbingBoxLoader
            size={60}
            color={"#36d7b7"}
            loading={loading}
            />
          <Typography className="welcome" variant="h2"> Welcome! </Typography>
        </div>
          )
        } else {
          return(
            <><AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
            <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Lumos - SocialXR</Typography>
          </AppBar><CreationSelection /></>
          )
        }



      }) ()}
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Update, I have added and initiated the const service = new Service(); right before the initiation of the isConnected one and now I am having the following error: "enhance your system component first"
[ERROR 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk6AN.png)

No clue what to do...

Comment: It seems that `Service.selectors` is undefined. Can you [edit] to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so it's clear where and how the `Service.selectors` is defined/declared, and exported/imported for use?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added where the selectors have been created in the Service.js file

Comment: Check this out, it will help you out: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: It is actually very obvious, for some reason `Service` is not defined (either not declared or imported incorrectly). See why Service is undefined or post a more complete code that we can debug.

Comment: @Dimitar I have posted the complete Service.js file

Comment: @Dimitar As well as my App.js file

Comment: @iLuca Did you instantiate `Service` ? As in `const service = new Service()`?

Comment: @DrewReese Added the full Service.js file as well as the App.js

Comment: @Dimitar hmmm I did not, where should I do it? I have just imported it in my App.js and then initiated the constant isConnected

Comment: After you instantiate a `Service` object where is the `enhance` method called? This is where I see `this._setSelectors` called.

Comment: I'll be completely honest, this everything-and-the-kitchen-sink service class seems completely out of place in React code. Speaking from personal experience OOP doesn't mix well with React patterns at all, it is like oil and water. I don't see any gain here using a class like this.

Comment: @DrewReese I was about to say, this is not the proper way to write react and redux code. Furthermore if OP doesnt't know that they need to instantiate a class, that probably means that they didn't write that class. My guess is that OP just copied this code from somewhere and is trying to get it to work, as most of us have in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is most likely that you do not `instantiate` your `Service` class.

You can do this by creating a `new` instance of `Service` like so:

```
const service = new Service()
```

As to where you'd do this, it is up to you. If you don't have instance-specific variables, then you can just instantiate the class once in your `Service.js` file and export it, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of the class (its supposed to be instantiated multiple times with different parameters and properties).

So then, the proper way would be to do it like so:

```
const service = new Service();
const isConnected = useSelector(service.selectors.selectIsConnected);
```

Now, looking at your code here, I can see that you are just returning a literal value not defined in the state, so I don't see the point of using the `useSelector` here, but I will give you the benefit of the doubt that you modify the `selectIsConnected` function somewhere in your code.

Comment: Ok ok so if I have understood this well, I would basically need to instantiate this const service = new Service() in my App.js file right above of the isConnected one. The backend connection architecture was indeed built by one of my colleagues in the past, and since now I am making a new client, I am trying to attach what he made with what I am making

Comment: Alright so I did add what you told me to, and now I am having "enhance your system component first" as an error.... Hmmmm

Comment: @iLuca that is thrown in your `_invalidateSelectors` method

Comment: indeed thank you, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: because for some reason it just gets thrown...

Comment: @iLuca the reason it gets thrown is because `this._invalidateSelectors()` is called. If you don't want it to get thrown, comment it out or delete it.

Comment: Alright, done, now it tells me that the CONNECTION_STATES is not defined... (man these errors) even though in the Service.js the CONNECTION_STATES is defined and can be exported. What would I need to do in the app.js

Comment: Import `CONNECTION_STATES` in your `App.js`.

Comment: import ```{ CONNECTION_STATES } from './global/service/Service'``` like this right?

Comment: Thank you in any case @Dimitar for your help, so regarding all these issues, everything seems to be fixe, however for some reason my client still doesn't connect itself to the backend XD